# How to bulk change external column values defined in Orders table and stored in database?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, bulkupdate

I am working on return processes in Woocommerce. I am getting returned or not returned information from table named *return_table*. I added this information to a new column in the orders table. The table is simply as follows:

[image: table-design]

I need to make changes to the column I just added. For example, I want to update the value from no return to returned. For this, I should make a new definition in the default actions column or add a new bulk action. I decided to add bulk action as it is more functional:

[image: bulk-action]

However, I was unable to make any progress after that. I've done research on Stackoverflow or other platforms. I found an answer to add buttons (new actions) but still couldn't solve the problem:
[Source-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916661/process-custom-bulk-action-on-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce)

Others I've found are mostly geared towards changing the "Order Status":
[Source-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202120/need-bulk-status-change-function-with-a-custom-woocommerce-order-status),  [Source-3](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/bulk-change-custom-order-status.html), [Source-4](https://wp-qa.com/need-bulk-status-change-function-with-a-custom-woocommerce-order-status)...
So, i've been researching this for a while and haven't found a solution. I will be grateful if anyone can help.

My Code:

```
<?php
// Add new column
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'return_column', 11);
function return_column( $columns ) { 
    $columns['return_column']  = 'Return Status';
    return $columns;
}

// Add the data to the custom columns
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'return_column_content',11);
function return_column_content ($column){
    if($column == 'return_column'){
        // Create required global variables 
        global $post, $wpdb;
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT return_status FROM {$wpdb->prefix}return_table WHERE order_id ='$order_id' LIMIT 1");
        if(count($result)):
            echo $result[0]->return_status;
        else:
            echo '-';
        endif;
    }
}

//Add new order status to bulk change 
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'refund_register_bulk_action' ); 
function refund_register_bulk_action( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['mark_returned']          = 'Returned'; 
    $bulk_actions['mark_not_returned']      = 'Not Returned'; 
    return $bulk_actions;
}
```

Comment: The 'difficulty' will be in using your custom table because you will need to provide custom SQL queries for it. Is there a specific reason why you are using a custom table versus adding this value as post meta? (which would make the answer to your question easier. 
As in [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917368/11987538), which you refer to in your question)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by storing it with the post meta array. Why database? The above is just an example. There is a lot of data. That's why I chose to use a database.